# Put validation of two array fields in JSON Schema using oneOf

Tags: jsonschema

Can I put check on two fields in JSON schema ? Both field are of type array of objects. Conditions:

1. Either one of them can contain value at a time (i.e. other should be empty).
2. Both can be empty.

Any leads ?

```
// The schema
var schema = {
    "id": "https://kitoutapi.lrsdedicated.com/v1/json_schemas/login-request#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Login request schema",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
       { "categories": {
        "maxItems": 0
    },
    "positionedOffers": {
      "minItems": 1
    }},
    { "categories": {
      "minItems": 1
    },
      "positionedOffers": {
        "maxItems": 0
      }}
    ],
    "properties": {
        "categories": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "positionedOffers": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
};

 
// Test data 1
// This test should return a good result
var data1 = {
    "positionedOffers":['hello'],
    "categories":[],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, I think I'd come at this from the other direction. Rather than saying

> If one contains a value, the other must be empty, but both may be empty.

I'd say

> At least one must be empty.

That leads you to use an `anyOf` with subschemas checking that each property is an empty array.

```json
{
  "id": "https://kitoutapi.lrsdedicated.com/v1/json_schemas/login-request#",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "Login request schema",
  "type": "object",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "categories": {
          "maxItems": 0
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "positionedOffers": {
          "maxItems": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "categories": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "positionedOffers": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

---

#### Bonus Material

In your original post, you omitted the `properties` keywords under the `oneOf`.  This may have been the cause of the schema's failure to validate.  I've added it in the above.

Secondly, draft 4 is quite old at this point.  You may be limited by the implementation you're using, but if you can, you should consider using a more recent version of JSON Schema.  You can view available implementations and what versions they support on the [JSON Schema implementations page](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html).